# Run executable from php without spawning a shell

Tags: php, performance, security, shell

I need to call an executable from an imposed context of a PHP script. Both performance and security wise it's better not to call a shell at all between web server process and executable.

Of course I searched the web, without success (in such a PHP context). Many other languages allow that and document it clearly.

Alas, backticks, `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `passthru()`, `system()`, `proc_open()`, `popen()` call a shell.
And `pcntl_fork()` seems unavailable.

## How to test if a function calls a shell or not.

This was tested on a Debian 6 64bit with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 .
Test code on http://pastebin.com/y4C7MeJz

To get a meaningful test I used a trick which is to ask to execute a shell command not also available as an executable. A good example is `umask` . Any function returning something like 0022 definitely called a shell. `exec()`, `shell_exec()`, `passthru()`, `system()`, `proc_open()` all did.
See detailed results on http://pastebin.com/RBcBz02F .

## pcntl_fork fails

Now, back the the goal : how to execute arbitrary program without launching a shell ?

Php's exec takes as expected an array of string args instead of a unique string. But pcntl_fork just stops the requests without even a log.

Edit: pcntl_fork failure is because the server uses Apache's mod_php, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#49949 .

Edit: added `popen()` to the tests, following @hakre suggestion.

Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

To answer your sentence :

> Both performance and security wise it's better not to call a shell at
>   all between web server process and executable.

About performances, well, yes, php internals forks, and the shell itself forks too so that's a bit heavy. But you really need to execute a lot of processes to consider those performances issues.

About security, I do not see any issue here. PHP has the [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) function to sanitize arguments.

The only real problem I met with `exec` without pcntl is not a resource nor security issue : it is really difficult to create *real* deamons (without any attachment to its parent, particularily *Apache*). I solved this by using `at`, after double-escaping my command:

```
$arg1 = escapeshellarg($arg1);
$arg2 = escapeshellarg($arg2);
$command = escapeshellarg("/some/bin $arg1 $arg2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
exec("$command | at now -M");
```

To get back to your question, the only way I know to execute programs in a *standard* (fork+exec) way is to use the [PCNTL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) extension (as already mentionned). Anyway, good luck!

---

To complete my answer, you can create an `exec` function yourself that does the same thing as `pcntl_fork`+`pcntl_exec`.

I made a `my_exec` extension that does a classic exec+fork, but actually, **I do not think it will solve your issues if you're running this function under apache**, because the same behaviour as `pcntl_fork` will apply (apache2 will be forked and there may be unexpected behaviours with signal catching and so on when `execv` does not succeed).

<kbd>config.m4</kbd> the `phpize` configuration file

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(my_exec_extension, whether to enable my extension,
[ --enable-my-extension   Enable my extension])

if test "$PHP_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION, 1, [Whether you have my extension])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(my_exec_extension, my_exec_extension.c, $ext_shared)
fi
```

<kbd>my_exec_extension.c</kbd> the extension

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
#include "php.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PHP_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION_VERSION "1.0"
#define PHP_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION_EXTNAME "my_exec_extension"

extern zend_module_entry my_exec_extension_module_entry;
#define phpext_my_exec_extension_ptr &my_exec_extension_module_entry

// declaration of a custom my_exec()
PHP_FUNCTION(my_exec);

// list of custom PHP functions provided by this extension
// set {NULL, NULL, NULL} as the last record to mark the end of list
static function_entry my_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(my_exec, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

// the following code creates an entry for the module and registers it with Zend.
zend_module_entry my_exec_extension_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION_EXTNAME,
    my_functions,
    NULL, // name of the MINIT function or NULL if not applicable
    NULL, // name of the MSHUTDOWN function or NULL if not applicable
    NULL, // name of the RINIT function or NULL if not applicable
    NULL, // name of the RSHUTDOWN function or NULL if not applicable
    NULL, // name of the MINFO function or NULL if not applicable
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    PHP_MY_EXEC_EXTENSION_VERSION,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(my_exec_extension)

char *concat(char *old, char *buf, int buf_len)
{
    int str_size = strlen(old) + buf_len;
    char *str = malloc((str_size + 1) * sizeof(char));
    snprintf(str, str_size, "%s%s", old, buf);
    str[str_size] = '\0';
    free(old);
    return str;
}

char *exec_and_return(char *command, char **argv)
{
    int link[2], readlen;
    pid_t pid;
    char buffer[4096];
    char *output;

    output = strdup("");

    if (pipe(link) < 0)
    {
        return strdup("Could not pipe!");
    }

    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        return strdup("Could not fork!");
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        dup2(link[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(link[0]);
        if (execv(command, argv) < 0)
        {
            printf("Command not found or access denied: %s\n", command);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        close(link[1]);

        while ((readlen = read(link[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0)
        {
            output = concat(output, buffer, readlen);
        }

        wait(NULL);
    }
    return output;
}

PHP_FUNCTION(my_exec)
{
    char *command;
    int command_len, argc, i;
    zval *arguments, **data;
    HashTable *arr_hash;
    HashPosition pointer;
    char **argv;

    // recovers a string (s) and an array (a) from arguments
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "sa", &command, &command_len, &arguments) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    arr_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(arguments);

    // creating argc and argv from our argument array
    argc = zend_hash_num_elements(arr_hash);
    argv = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char *));
    argv[argc] = NULL;

    for (
            i = 0, zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
            zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void**) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
            zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)
        )
    {
        if (Z_TYPE_PP(data) == IS_STRING) {
            argv[i] = malloc((Z_STRLEN_PP(data) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            argv[i][Z_STRLEN_PP(data)] = '\0';
            strncpy(argv[i], Z_STRVAL_PP(data), Z_STRLEN_PP(data));
            i++;
        }
    }

    char *output = exec_and_return(command, argv);

    // freeing allocated memory
    for (i = 0; (i < argc); i++)
    {
        free(argv[i]);
    }
    free(argv);

    // WARNING! I guess there is a memory leak here.
    // Second arguemnt to 1 means to PHP: do not free memory
    // But if I put 0, I get a segmentation fault
    // So I think I do not malloc correctly for a PHP extension.
    RETURN_STRING(output, 1);
}
```

<kbd>test.php</kbd> a usage sample

```
<?php

dl("my_exec.so");

$output = my_exec("/bin/ls", array("-l", "/"));
var_dump($output);
```

<kbd>shell script</kbd> run those commands, of course use your own module directory

```
phpize
./configure
make
sudo cp modules/my_exec_extension.so /opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/my_exec.so
```

<kbd>Result</kbd>

```
KolyMac:my_fork ninsuo$ php test.php
string(329) ".DS_Store
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
.file
.fseventsd
.hidden
.hotfiles.btree
.vol
AppleScript
Applications
Developer
Installer Log File
Library
Microsoft Excel Documents
Microsoft Word Documents
Network
System
Users
Volumes
bin
cores
dev
etc
home
lost+found
mach_kernel
net
opt
private
sbin
tmp
usr
var
vc_command.txt
vidotask.txt"
```

I am not a C dev, so I think there are cleaner ways to achieve this. But you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer. It spans two topics about PHP : first, accept to fork a useless shell and work around security (escapeshellargs), and second how to create daemons (that part steps off the question asked). See George Cummins's bounty.

Comment: Security is a problem with any shell exec in any programming language, because most shells (sh, ash, bash, ksh, csh, tcsh, etc.) are slightly different and have different reserved characters with special meaning. Escapeshellarg() is a dangerous illusion of security. Not to mention that historically, escapeshellarg() has itself had vulnerabilities. If you don't need a shell, it's far safer not to use one. This is security 101: reduce attack surface area.

Comment: You mentioned `escapeshellarg`.  Now we know about the 22-year-old ([ref](http://www.informationweek.com/government/cybersecurity/shellshock-bug-6-key-facts--/d/d-id/1316131) ) shellshock bug, https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8371357 says: "Sanitization is an orthogonal issue; no amount of escapeshellarg() would save someone from this issue (...)"  Security requires to not introduce unneeded security holes.  Calling a shell when not technically needed does just that.

Comment: escapeshellarg() is dumb. If the shell suddenly happens to be not what PHP assumes, it instantly becomes a liability. Besides, it does not work at all under Windows.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 7.4+, [proc_open](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php#refsect1-function.proc-open-parameters) open processes directly if `cmd` is passed as array.

> As of PHP 7.4.0, cmd may be passed as array of command parameters. In this case the process will be opened directly (without going through a shell) and PHP will take care of any necessary argument escaping.

So this example:

```
<?php
$file_descriptors = [
        0=>['pipe','r'],
        1=>['pipe','w'],
        2=>['pipe','w']
];
$cmd_string = 'ps -o comm=';
$cmd_array = [
        'ps',
        '-o',
        'comm='
];

// This is executed by shell:
$process = proc_open($cmd_string,$file_descriptors,$pipes);
$output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$return = proc_close($process);
printf("cmd_string:\n%s\n",$output);

// This is executed directly:
$process = proc_open($cmd_array,$file_descriptors,$pipes);
$output = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$return = proc_close($process);
printf("cmd_array:\n%s\n",$output);
```

outputs:

```
cmd_string:
bash
php
sh
ps

cmd_array:
bash
php
ps
```

Answer (score 0):

Id consider trying [pcntl_exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/function.pcntl-exec.php)

Comment: Read the pastebin: `PCNTL functions not available on this PHP installation.`

Comment: Indeed : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#49949 "It is not possible to use the function 'pcntl_fork' when PHP is used as Apache module."

Comment: Regardless what is written in doc, pcntl_fork() can be used when PHP is Apache module. However it will fork whole Apache server.