# how to run perl script inside php without by terminal linux

Tags: php, perl

I have a perl script which i have to run in php code. Here is my perl script.

```
perl /var/www/app/site_by_corp.pl &
```

I was running this perl script in terminal by manual. Now i want to run this inside php code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run executable from php without spawning a shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16595044/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec`

```
exec("perl /var/www/app/site_by_corp.pl &", $output);
```